# Trimble Pathfinder giving error closing geodatabase when exporting to fIle geodatabase

Tags: esri-geodatabase, trimble, pathfinder

I am getting an error on various files when trying to export their .cor files to a file geodatabase.  The error message is

> An error occurred while closing the geodatabase.
> Unexpected operation.  File exp1019b.txt contains a detailed log

However the detailed log shows this:

```
Reading file LAW003-DW-20210315.cor
File LAW003-DW-20210315.cor read successfully
An error occurred while closing the geodatabase. Unexpected operation.
An error occurred while closing the geodatabase. Unexpected operation.
```

I have had this in the past and had to export to shapefile, which it does successfully, so I am thinking the error on closing the geodatabase is happening on closing the one being created.  I want to avoid export to shapefile as I need the proper-length attribute field names.

Why is the geodatabase not closing?  It works successfully on other .cor files, and nothing has changed in my export settings for file geodatabases.

Comment: geodatabase field names must be SQL compliant and only allow an underscore (_) as a special character (No other special characters are permitted),  https://community.esri.com/t5/esri-technical-support-blog/words-by-reservation-only/ba-p/898664

Comment: All field names are compliant.  Other files collected with the same data dictionary and named in a similar naming convention are exporting to GDB fine, so I still can't figure why a handful of them give this error on export.